# Is there any way to detect the user clicked my provided URL?

Tags: python-2.7, python-telegram-bot

i used **python-telegram-bot** module and used 
**InlineKeyboardButton** with (text, url, callback_data) to detect click event, but
with url arguments, they just redirect to link and don't send callback_data to query.

```
select_list.append(InlineKeyboardButton('myText',url=url,callback_data='identifer'))
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible, the arguments are mutually exlusive, you may only pass a `url=` or a `callback_data=`. They don't work simultaneous.

You can read more about InlineKeyboardButtons [here](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.inlinekeyboardbutton.html)